# WSREP: Failed to prepare for 'rsync' SST. Unrecoverable

Tags: mysql, percona-xtradb-cluster

I ma using Percona Xtradb Cluster with 5 nodes.

I used mysqld --console to trace and see this error

```
WSREP: Failed to prepare for 'rsync' SST. Unrecoverable.


Quote:
130320 18:49:37 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --log-slave-updates work.
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so'
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 2.3(r143) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded succesfully.
130320 18:49:37 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: /sbin/ifconfig | grep -E '^[[:space:]]+inet addr:' | grep -m1 -v 'inet addr:127' | sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{ print $3 }': 2 (No such file or directory)
130320 18:49:37 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to guess base node address. Set it explicitly via wsrep_node_address.
130320 18:49:37 [Warning] WSREP: Guessing address for incoming client connections failed. Try setting wsrep_node_incoming_address explicitly.
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 9ad38334-9082-11e2-0800-6edb31989fd4:-1
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Reusing existing '/var/lib/mysql//galera.cache'.
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = NO; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = NO; pc.ignore_sb = true; replicator.causal_read_timeout = PT30S; replicator.commit_order = 3
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: (70fd13f2-91b0-11e2-0800-73cacdb90501, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: (70fd13f2-91b0-11e2-0800-73cacdb90501, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: PC version 0
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'eclickz', peer '192.168.133.66:'
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: (70fd13f2-91b0-11e2-0800-73cacdb90501, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers: tcp://192.168.133.68:4567
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: (70fd13f2-91b0-11e2-0800-73cacdb90501, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: declaring 60a03c55-919b-11e2-0800-5b5a359d2cb3 stable
130320 18:49:37 [Note] WSREP: declaring c96d5052-918c-11e2-0800-210b57b08c72 stable
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,60a03c55-919b-11e2-0800-5b5a359d2cb3,352) memb {
60a03c55-919b-11e2-0800-5b5a359d2cb3,
70fd13f2-91b0-11e2-0800-73cacdb90501,
c96d5052-918c-11e2-0800-210b57b08c72,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'eclickz'
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 1, memb_num = 3
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 45816f5a-91b0-11e2-0800-a4fd5a8bbd3c
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 45816f5a-91b0-11e2-0800-a4fd5a8bbd3c from 0 (node03)
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 45816f5a-91b0-11e2-0800-a4fd5a8bbd3c from 2 (node1)
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 45816f5a-91b0-11e2-0800-a4fd5a8bbd3c from 1 (slave5.eclickz.com)
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
version = 2,
component = PRIMARY,
conf_id = 346,
members = 2/3 (joined/total),
act_id = 832701,
last_appl. = -1,
protocols = 0/4/2 (gcs/repl/appl),
group UUID = 9ad38334-9082-11e2-0800-6edb31989fd4
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [28, 28]
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 832701)
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
Group state: 9ad38334-9082-11e2-0800-6edb31989fd4:832701
Local state: 9ad38334-9082-11e2-0800-6edb31989fd4:-1
130320 18:49:38 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 9ad38334-9082-11e2-0800-6edb31989fd4:832701, view# 347: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 1, protocol version 2
130320 18:49:38 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
130320 18:49:40 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '192.168.133.70:4567' --auth '' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --parent '38994''
130320 18:49:40 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read 'ready <addr>' from: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '192.168.133.70:4567' --auth '' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --parent '38994'
Read: '(null)'
130320 18:49:40 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '192.168.133.70:4567' --auth '' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --parent '38994': 2 (No such file or directory)
130320 18:49:40 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to prepare for 'rsync' SST. Unrecoverable.
130320 18:49:40 [ERROR] Aborting

130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Closing send monitor...
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Closed send monitor.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,60a03c55-919b-11e2-0800-5b5a359d2cb3,3 52) memb {
70fd13f2-91b0-11e2-0800-73cacdb90501,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
60a03c55-919b-11e2-0800-5b5a359d2cb3,
c96d5052-918c-11e2-0800-210b57b08c72,
})
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = no, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Received NON-PRIMARY.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> OPEN (TO: 832701)
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Received self-leave message.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [0, 0]
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Received SELF-LEAVE. Closing connection.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> CLOSED (TO: 832701)
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: RECV thread exiting 0: Success
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: recv_thread() joined.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Closing slave action queue.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
130320 18:49:42 [Note] WSREP: rollbacker thread exiting
130320 18:49:43 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
```

One more thing, some other nodes can start but not bind port 3306. that's weird.

I could not resolve this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Try Checking the selinux status. It should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by installing libssl0.9.8.